# Why doesn't the compiler convert var[] to object[] in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, object, new-operator

There is no difference between these two lines, because the compiler, in the second line, understands that it is an array of type **int**.

```
var x = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };   //Fine, x is int[]
var x = new [] { 1, 2, 3 };      //Fine, x is int[]
```

But why can't I do this with different types? Why doesn't the compiler convert my variable to type **object**?

```
var x = new object[] { 1, "df", 5 };   //Fine, x is object[]
var x = new [] { 1, "df", 5 };         //Error! "No best type found for implicity-typed-array"
```

**EDIT:**

Thanks for all your answers. But I still wonder, what are the pros and cons to make all expressions that the compiler can't convert to type `object`? (Because I use `var` notation which means that it can't be any type. I understand like this.) Why doesn't the compiler find the nearest type of the array members by going up the inheritance tree?

Comment: Yes, but question mostly is "why isn't it implemented by this way?"

Comment: Damien_The_Unbeliever's comment on Joey's answer says it all, really. It's just too much work for the compiler, not to mention the inferring `object[]` as a result is pretty counter-intuitive to me.

Comment: Perhaps its because the langauge designers think object arrays stink and they don't want it to be easy to use C# in a smelly way.

Comment: FYI, the `var` keyword has nothing to do with your question. `object[] x = new[] { 1, "df" };` doesn't work either.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The `new []` notation is for saving you to type an explicit type of the array members (or allowing you to create arrays where its elements have an anonymous type), but its type inference is limited in that all elements must share the same type or be implicitly convertible to a common type shared by at least one member. See C# Specification, section 7.6.10.4:

> An array creation expression of the third form is referred to as an implicitly typed array creation expression. It is similar to the second form, except that the element type of the array is not explicitly given, but determined as the best common type (§7.5.2.14) of the set of expressions in the array initializer.
>
> The following are examples of implicitly typed array creation expressions:
>
> ```
> var a = new[] { 1, 10, 100, 1000 };                       // int[]
> var b = new[] { 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5 };                         // double[]
> var c = new[,] { { "hello", null }, { "world", "!" } };   // string[,]
> var d = new[] { 1, "one", 2, "two" };                     // Error
> ```
>
> The last expression causes a compile-time error because neither `int` nor `string` is implicitly convertible to the other, and so there is no best common type. An explicitly typed array creation expression must be used in this case, for example specifying the type to be `object[]`. Alternatively, one of the elements can be cast to a common base type, which would then become the inferred element type.

Key point here is that the “best common type” can only be one of the types already present. As  [Damien_The_Unbeliever](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15498/damien-the-unbeliever) pointed out in a comment: *“As Mr. Lippert is fond of pointing out around inference, whenever it's looking for a best common type, it will only return one of the types that is already present - it doesn't go hunting for the most-derived common ancestor.”*.

Just because every array could be an `object []` doesn't mean it should. From a compiler perspective that'd be a trivial last-resort choice, but a very counter-intuitive one for the developer, I guess.

Comment: And why new[] isn't implemented to provide such convertion too? What're the cons of that?

Comment: No, the new[] notation is mainly for faciliating arrays of anonymous types. Saving typing is just a nice side effect.

Comment: The *why* might be something Eric Lippert might be able to answer. I'm a little fuzzy on the history but full-blown type inference came with `var`, maybe `new []` predates that.

Comment: Add a `new Object()` into the array, and it compiles fine. As Mr. Lippert is fond of pointing out around inference, whenever it's looking for a best common type, it will only return one of the types that is already present - it doesn't go hunting for the most-derived common ancestor.

Comment: Damien, thanks. I added that. To be honest, that part of the spec is quite hard to understand if you dive right in.

Comment: @Joey var arr = new[] { new { Prop = 5 }, new { Prop = 6 } };

Edit: I am pretty sure there was a comment that asked how I would declare an array of anonymous type.

Comment: Stilgar, found the example already and also remembered that you can just stick references into the array you had from earlier. Hence the deletion of my comment.

Answer (score 18):

To expand on Joey's answer, consider this example:

```
interface IFoo { }
interface IBar { }

class A : IFoo, IBar { }
class B : IFoo, IBar { }

var array = new [] { new A(), new B() };
```

Both classes implement both interfaces (and also derive from `object`), so which type should be inferred for `array`?

---

To answer your comment, consider the case where `A` and `B` share only one interface:

```
interface IFoo { }

class A : IFoo { }
class B : IFoo { }

var array = new [] { new A(), new B() };
```

Both `A` and `B` share `object` as their base class, but it'd be unhelpful and mostly useless to infer this for the array type. One would expect it to be `IFoo` if anything, so it would violate the [principle of least astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment). However, this cannot be done consistently, as I've illustrated.

The safest and most consistent behaviour here is simply not to allow type inference.

Comment: +1. We always tend to forget that .NET *does* support multiple inheritance (although only through interfaces).

Comment: Yeah, fine example. But why in this example he can't convert to object. He can find the nearest type they both are inherited. There isn't multiple inheritance, so he can search by single branch of tree...

Comment: @mesiesta: They may only have one common base *class*, but why should this take precedence over their implemented interfaces? Interfaces are types too.

Comment: Yeah, I know... I mean to not to look at interfaces at all... Just look to base class(there can be only one).

Comment: But why are base classes more important than interfaces? See my update: sometimes interfaces are more important than base classes.